# How to make all features compile to modules in kernel compilation?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

When I use make menuconfig, I saw many optional modules which I can chose (using 'M') to make it compile as a module. What I want is to compile all features which can be compiled to a module as modules but I don't want to select manually in menuconfig window. Could anyone give me some advice? Dose 'make modules' make sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for

`make allmodconfig`

From `make -f Makefile help` states: **New config selecting modules when possible**

This option sets configuration as "M" wherever possible.